# Returning New Lines

Tags: java, string

```
public String toString()
{
    String name = "Customer name: " + this.name;
    String address = "Customer address: " +  street +  " " + city + " " + state + " " + zip;
    String bala = "Balance: " + bal;

    return name + "\n" + address + "\n" + bala;
}
```

I want these variables to be returned in three separate lines, but the actual string "\n" is just being added where I want the new line to be. Any help?

Comment: did you try to print it? The new line will show up when you print it, otherwise its just a special character in string as \n

Comment: Okay so how do I create a new line if I am not printing it?

Comment: \n is new line. If you do something like .readLine() it will read it line by line. Its a representation of new line

Comment: How are you using this method? It should be working fine (assuming your OS supports `\n` as line separator).

Comment: How are you testing how this String is displayed? By printing it to the console?

Comment: how would you know if the vars are not being returned as three separate lines? if you print them then definitely they will be on three separate lines. also, if you really want them to be separate, why not return an array or list? that way it would be easier for you to identify

Comment: System.lineSeparator() will create the new line.  Also, maybe you should try using a StringBuffer object instead of concatenations, since it will make things a little bit easier on your memory usage.

Comment: It is just a regular toString() method, but my prof wants each variable on it's own line. I know it is not on three separate lines because the string that the debugger is showing is just the variables separated by "\n", not a new line.

Comment: Jack just print it man, it will print in new lines. Debugger is showing the content of the string which WILL contain \n.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but may work :

```
return name + System.lineSeparator() + address + System.lineSeparator() + bala;
```

Comment: I think both can work. I can't try it right now, if you can, feedback me !